# Process Builder not working on update properly

Tags: lightning, process-builder

Hi I have requirement as follows :

Whenever client make the checkbox true and select the Contact as lookup in the Case object then particular contact information must get copied to the Contact object.

Process builder Logic as follows:

```
AND(
    OR(
        [Case].Contact_same_on_Job_Site__c, 
        AND(
            PRIORVALUE([Case].ContactId) <> [Case].ContactId,
            [Case].Contact_same_on_Job_Site__c
        )
    ),
    OR(
        [Case].RecordType.Name= 'Customer Request',
        [Case].RecordType.Name= 'Advanced Field Request'
    )
)
```

Every Scenario is working fine except below:

Checkbox is true and then we update the contact then Process Builder is not updating the given contact info from the site.

Comment: Your screenshot did not get correctly posted; use [edit]

Comment: Please log into this account to make edits to your question and its tags. Contact Stack Exchange via the link at the bottom of the page to have your duplicate accounts merged.